# Element not visible, selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to a site.

This is the problematic html part:

```
<input name="pass" id="vic_login_password" autocomplete="off" class="inpHM3_2" dir="ltr" type="password" value="" id="PasswprdH1" /><input type="text" value="Password" onfocus="this.style.display='none'; gid('vic_login_password').style.display='block'; gid('vic_login_password').focus();" class="inpHM3_3" />
```

My code:

```
driver.findElementById("vic_login_password").SendKeys "fakepass"
```

I get an error no -2146233088 saying that element is not visible.

For the user name everything works fine this way, but for the password I always get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to solve the problem is inside that `onfocus()` event handler:

```
onfocus="this.style.display='none'; gid('vic_login_password').style.display='block'; gid('vic_login_password').focus();"
```

It is actually making one input invisible and the other one visible. The other one is the input with `id="vic_login_password"` which is initially invisible. This explains the error you've got.

In your code, you should first focus the visible input and only then send keys to the other one:

```
driver.findElementByCssSelector("input[value=Password][onfocus]").Click
driver.findElementById("vic_login_password").SendKeys "fakepass"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply and explanation, now I understand clearly what was the problem.
However it seems that there is a problem with this line:
driver.findElementByCssSelector("input[type=password][onfocus]").Click
I changed it to type='password' but I got another error which says element not found. Error message: "Element not found. Method = cssselector, value = input[type='password'][onfocus]).Click
What could be the problem with this line?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @hunsnowboarder oops, sorry, fixed the selector.

Comment: Yep! Works like a charm. Password was the problem!  Thank you so much! :)